# php MongoDB access failed from browser

Tags: php, mongodb, apache

I installed the Mongodb.so and necessary php libraries, it's working file on command line using following test code, but visit the same file on browser keep giving error(running on Apache 2.4+php 5.6), could someone give me a hint?

Fatal error: Class 'MongoDB\Driver\Manager' not found in ./vendor/mongodb/mongodb/src/Client.php on line 56

the test code as following:

```
<?php
$filename='./vendor/autoload.php';
require $filename;
$client = new MongoDB\Client("mongodb://localhost:27017");
$collection = $client->demo->beers;
$result = $collection->insertOne( ['name' => 'Hinterland', 'brewery' => 'BrewDog'] );
echo "Inserted with Object ID '{$result->getInsertedId()}'";
?>
```

also, the command line check shows the libarary already loaded into php
php -m|grep mongo mongodb

Comment: Hint: Did you add the mongodb extension to the correct `php.ini` file, there are normally 2, 1 for Apache use, and one for PHP CLI use. You obviously amended the PHP CLI version, but probably missed the Apache version

Comment: the php.ini file is the same, but the cli one is using different folder for additional .ini files /etc/php-zts.d, so I copied over the mongodb.ini over, now I can see the /etc/php-zts.d/mongodb.ini is loaded in the phpinfo page, I still don't see mogodb item in the list, and the same error still shows when visiting test url from browser, any idea how to resolve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Do not miss checking out the error log file for details. Your CLI and web scripts may be accessing different paths or libraries. Make sure that the php.ini file is same of same path in both environments. The aim is to use same library files in both the cases.

Comment: i double checked, php -i shows config file is /etc/php.ini

Comment: phpinfo on browser also shows /etc/php.ini as config file, also the additional loading file both contains mongodb.ini file which loads mangodb.so file. the same mongodb.so can be used in php cli without problem, however, the httpd error_log file does show error: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib64/php-zts/modules/mongodb.so', mongodb.so: undefined symbol: file_globals in Unknown on line 0

Comment: some more info from the error_log file, please advise how to fix the problem?PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib64/php-zts/modules/mongodb.so' - /usr/lib64/php-zts/modules/mongodb.so: undefined symbol: file_globals in Unknown on line 0

Comment: You can try moving mongodb.so into PHP's common extension_dir with the same chown/chmod permissions alike other existing extensions.

Comment: I put the file on PHP's common extension_dir, didn't help. PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib64/php/modules/mongodb.so' - /usr/lib64/php/modules/mongodb.so: undefined symbol: file_globals in Unknown on line 0

Comment: does different version of php api matters? this is what I get
phpize --version
Configuring for:
PHP Api Version:         20131106
Zend Module Api No:      20131226
Zend Extension Api No:   220131226

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the path environment variable. I had to alter the path to run php7 correctly. I had a php5 path setted there.